# Resising bandwith limit for google compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm setting up a project in order to make a classifier with 80000 images.
For the moment, the bandwith limit for uploading image to my compute engine is 100 Ko/s, which promises me a lot of time to achieve this. Is there a way to change this ? Is there something in the quota for this ?
Thank you.

Comment: GCE instances have a limit of 2 Gbit per core. How are you determining a different limit? Perhaps your Internet connection is the bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

On GCP the network egress limits is proportional to the vCPU count and also depends on the size of IOs, (16 KB IOs consumes more bandwidth than 8 KB IOs at the same IOPS level).

If you want to optimize the performance at bandwidth level, then you need to determine the best disk for your VM. By resizing your persistent disks, you will increase IOPS and throughput per persistent disk.

In [document section "Network egress caps on write throughput](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance#egress_performance_cap) this is explained:

Standard persistent disk IOPS and throughput performance increases linearly with the size of the disk until it reaches the following per-instance limits:

Read throughput: Up to 240 MB/s at a 2 TB disk size.
Write throughput: Up to 240 MB/s at a 2 TB disk size.
Read IOPS: Up to 3,000 IOPS at a 4 TB disk size.
Write IOPS: Up to 15,000 IOPS at a 10 TB disk size.